# How can I sum the values of specific array's item?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 10
            [range] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 5
            [range] => today
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 5
            [range] => yesterday
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 15
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 10
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 5
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [numb] => 15
            [range] => in last month or more
        )
)
*/
```

Always there is 4 or less cases:

- today
- yesterday
- in last week
- in last month or more

And I'm trying to sum the `numb` item where `range` is `today` and there is another case in the `$results` array *(or yesterday, or in last week, or in last month or more, or some of them, or all of them, doesn't matter .. Just there should be one more case except "today")*.

How can I do that?

---

```
$score = null;
foreach($results as item) {
    if ( $item[range] == 'today' && /* another case exists */ ) {
        $score = item['numb'];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I wrote that `break` because the items are sorted in the array. I mean always `today`'s items are either not exist or in the top of the array. So if that condition is `FALSE` then it also will be `FALSE` for the rest of items.

Comment: you could use a CASE here with `SUM()`, directly in your query or `SUM IF`, but that may be more complex than doing it in PHP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answers are missing a couple of keys he asked for in the question.  He is looking to sum entries that are "today" if (and only if) there exist some entry in the array that isn't "today".  While I agree the structure of the current array isn't ideal for this task, for the sake of simplicity, we will keep it and break it into a couple of steps

```
//first lets scan the array to see if there is something that is not "today"
$allTodays = true;
foreach ($result as $row) {
   if($row['range'] !== 'today') {
    $allTodays = false;
    break;
  }
}
// now if there is something that is not today
// sum the todays
$score = null;
if (!$allTodays) {
  foreach ($results as $item) {
    if ($item['range'] == 'today') {
        $score += item['numb'];
    } else {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

You were pretty close I feel like.

Note: This may not be the most elegant solution, but it's a simple and straight-forward solution that should be easy to follow.

Comment: You have an if condition inside of a foreach loop inside of an if condition - this is considered a malpractice nowadays. One level is ok (but some choose to avoid even that)

Comment: I'm interested to hear why this is "malpractice", the cost of executing this conditional on N objects should still be linear time.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
$score = 0;
foreach($results as $item) {
    if ( $item['range'] == 'today') {
        $score += item['numb'];
    }
}
var_dump($score); // The sum total of all the $result array's "numb" values
```

Answer (score -2):

you can change the array structure in order to sum :

```
<?php
$sums = array();
// init
foreach($results as $item) {
     if($item['range'] == 'today') { // if you only want today add this condition
         if (!array_key_exists($item['range'], $sums)) {
             $sums[$item['range']] = 0;
         }
         $sums[$item['range']] += $item['numb'];
     }
}

// $sums['in last week'] will contain 30
```

Comment: Where is `$item[range] == 'today'` ? I just want to calculate the total of `today`.

Comment: `$sums['today']` will contain `today` sum

Answer (score -3):

If I understand you correctly, your task is a very common one - you want to group items first (based on 'range' field), then calculate sums.

The easiest solution, perhaps, is to store results for each range in an associative array:

```
$scores = [];

foreach ($results as $item) {
    if (! isset($scores[$item['range']])) {
        $scores[$item['range']] = $item['num'];
    } else {
        $scores[$item['range']] += $item['num'];
    }
}

print_r($scores);
```

Comment: Where is `$item[range] == 'today'` ? I just want to calculate the total of `today`.

Comment: It's in $scores['today'], it's quite obvious if you do print_r() :)